# Or operator not displaying content

Tags: php, stripos

Im trying to get something to be echoed if the user is on one of the two pages, but it isn't echoed

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'user.php') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'message.php')) {
echo 'hello';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will give you the URI which was given in order to access this page, not the actual page name. Use `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` to get the actual page name.

And second, the condition of your `if` clause is also wrong. From [the manual of `stripos()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginnning of the haystack string (independent of offset). **Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1**.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

So both of your conditions will fails if the needle matches exactly with the haystack. Instead check the condition like this:

```
if(stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false || stripos(stripos($haystack, $needle)) !== false) {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

So **the solution** is like this:

```
if(stripos(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 'user.php') !== false || stripos(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 'message.php') !== false) {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'user.php') || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'message.php')) {
echo 'hello';
}
```

Notice the stripos function in the clause after ||.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each conditional argument in its own block with parenthesis. Every function added to the condition must include 2 parenthesis.

```
IF ( ($a == $x) or ($b == $y) ) {}

if (
    (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'user.php')) ||
    (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'message.php')) 
) {
  echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer and not just give a block of code.